# Some questions about special relativty

Tags: special-relativity

If one wants to talk about special relativity and Lorentz transformation he/she should first talk about why we need Lorentz transformation at all. The Lorentz transformation was first discovered by Voight who required the covariance of physical laws (namely Euler's 3D wave equation) between inertial reference frames and the constancy of speed of light measured by observers in all inertial reference frames. The reason why we need the Lorentz transformation is to ensure the covariance (i.e. Euler's 3d wave equation must take the same mathematical form) in all inertial frames of reference. The constancy of the speed of light is required (and implied in Voight's work), otherwise, we cannot derive the Lorentz transformation.

Regarding the Lorentz transformation, I have three questions for which I would be very thankful if someone can clarify these for me:

#1 The speed of light is constant in all inertial frames of reference relative to what? we always measure the speed of something relative to something. We cant talk about the speed of anything without the pivot point. Is it constant when measured relative to the source or relative to something else?

#2  why no other physical law (except the wave equation) is required to obey the covariance? In other words, why don't we say that Newton's law of cooling, and Hooke's law must obey the same equation in all inertial frames of reference? What type of transformation between inertial frames we would get if these laws were required to be the same in all inertial frames of reference? Does this mean that the wave equation is the most fundamental physical law and that other physical laws are irrelevant when compared to the wave equation?

#3 If Einstein desired, he could have written his 1905 paper (at least part not including electromagnetics) with sound as a method of signaling. He would arrive at the same conclusions but with the speed of sound (constancy of the speed of sound and Lorentz transformation at the speed of sound). How can his theory be correct if we can derive an equivalent theory (theory of special relativity) at the speed of sound?

Comment: Sound is fundamentally different, because what matters is speed with respect to the fluid medium in which the waves are propagating.  If you have a headwind of 400 m/s (supersonic) the phenomena will be qualitatively different.  Light has no propagation medium (in a vacuum).

Answer (score 3):

1- The speed of light is constant in every reference frame relative to an object at rest in said frame. Defining a reference frame includes a notion of being at rest. If you picture the reference frame of a spaceship as three Cartesian axes glued to it, than in this frame the ship itself is at rest in the origin, and the speed of light is $c$ relative to this origin (or any other point stationary with respect to the origin).

2- All physical laws are required to obey Lorentz covariance. This is called the first postulate of special relativity. However, in many cases one is worried about phenomena happening at low energies, where the speeds of the relevant objects are so small compared to the speed of light that relativistic effects become irrelevant. So one may discard these, and that is how you end up with laws that do not respect Lorentz covariance, but nevertheless work very well at low energies. By the way, people usually don't regard the wave equation as a physical law. It is an equation that describes approximately the behavior of many systems. For instance, Maxwell's equations are the laws that govern electromagnetic phenomena. In some situations, the solutions to these equations (the electric and magnetic fields) can behave as waves, but not always.

3- I think you are thinking about this backwards. Einstein would have not arrived at the same conclusion as he did for the speed of light for that of sound. He was not trying to force physical laws to be Lorentz covariant just for the sake of it. He knew that the electrodynamics of Maxwell's equations already gave you the same laws in every reference frame, and that the speed of electromagnetic waves (light) indeed comes out as the same in each of them. At the time this was just a poorly understood feature of electromagnetic theory, and not of the mechanics of sound waves. He later postulated that all fundamental physical laws, like the Maxwell equations were thought to be, should have the same form in all reference frames. However, as I said, in most cases (such as the ones related to the propagation of sound), this only introduces minute corrections to the quantities of interest at the price of making the calculations a lot harder to do, so one may ignore relativistic effects in these cases. If you try to neglect special relativity for high energy systems, your calculations will give totally wrong results.